# $pipeline is not a list (unexpected index: "$group") in Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

When the below query is run the results are displayed in mongo shell.

**Sample Records**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587e21df6e79d255011a9c6a"),
    "vendor_id" : "101",
    "subscription_id" : 14,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T13:53:35.272Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587e21df6e79d255011a9c6c"),
    "vendor_id" : "102",
    "subscription_id" : 14,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T13:56:35.272Z")
}
```

**Query**

```
db.user_config.aggregate({$group: 
{
    _id : "$subscription_id", 
    list: 
    { 
        $push:  
        { 
            _id: "$_id", 
            vendor_id: "$vendor_id"
        } 
     }
}})
```

**Results**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 14,
            "list" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("587e21df6e79d255011a9c6a"),
                    "vendor_id" : "user_101"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("587e21df6e79d255011a9c6b"),
                    "vendor_id" : "user_101"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

But when same thing is done through laravel the following error occurs. $pipeline is not a list (unexpected index: "$group")

Below is the laravel code

```
$configuration_list = UserConfig::raw()->aggregate([
            '$group' => [
                    '_id'    => '$subscription_id',
                    'list'  => ['$push' => 
                     ['_id' => '$_id', 'vendor_id' => '$vendor_id']]
                ]
            ]
        );
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

[Wrap the aggregation pipeline steps in an array](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/880):

```
$pipeline = [
    [
        '$group' => [
            '_id' => '$subscription_id',
            'list' => [
                '$push' => [
                    '_id' => '$_id', 
                    'vendor_id' => '$vendor_id'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$configuration_list = UserConfig::raw()->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Comment: i tried with your code and even earlier but empty response is returned. Actually result is expected since same query gives result in mongo shell